# installing gdal on mac os sierra

Tags: django, macos, gdal

I have a Django project that I want to install and it uses GDAL. The documentation refers me to this [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/) in the Django documentation. I have been able to install GEOS and PROJ.4. I wanted to use the latest GDAL which is 2.2.1 and ./configure command failed so I followed [this](http://adventuresindevelopment.blogspot.co.ke/2009/04/compile-gdal-with-geotiff-support.html) instructions and it compiled. However, make command now fails with the following error

```
In file included from cpl_odbc.cpp:30:
/Users/DNG/gdal-2.2.1/port/cpl_odbc.h:39:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found
#include <sql.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [cpl_odbc.o] Error 1
make: *** [port-target] Error 2
```

`sudo find / -name sql.h` outputs:

```
find: /dev/fd/DNG: No such file or directory
find: /dev/fd/DNG: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/include/sql.h
/usr/local/include/sql.h
/usr/local/php5-7.0.18-20170506-095200/include/sql.h
```